# Draw pie slice with Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have three points on my map and I want to draw a "slice of pie" on it based on these points, I literally have no idea where to start with this so here is the information I have.

```
latitude and longitude of the centre of the circle
latitude and longitude of the top left & top right of the slice
```

I also have a circle already drawn on the map using these details, so here is what I currently have

[image: what i have]

And here is what I wish to achieve

[image: what I need]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this example can help ?

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_arc.html

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks mate, will let you know how I get on.